# Expressing an integer as root and power

Tags: python

I am currently learning python and this was the code I wrote to expres an integer in the form of a root and its power. While other answers on the website utilize a while loop, I want to improve and make my code more elegant using a for loop. I also have included the negative roots if any for the entered positive numbers. What can I do to improve this ? I am using John Guttag's book with the OCW course and have just an elementary idea of stuff. There will always be a root and power pair so the root not found line seems useless to me.

```
alpha=int(input("Enter an integer to find all its roots:"))
root=0
found=False
if alpha >=0:
    for power in range (1,6):
        for root in range(alpha+1):
            if root**power==alpha:
                print("Root:",root,"power:",power)
                found=True
                if power in range(2,6,2) and root!=0:
                    print("Root:",-root,"Power",power)       
elif alpha<0:
    for power in range (1,6):
        for root in range(0,alpha-1,-1):
            if root**power==alpha:
                print("Root :",root,"power: ",power)
                found= True
if not found:
    print("No such root and power pair is possible for",alpha)
```

Comment: Note: only use the python3 tag if the question is related to some issue specific to the python3 version.  That is, not just because you are running python3.

Comment: This type of *How to improve my code* questions are better suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Take some time reading the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask good questions, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: What is the significance of '6'?  Why do you think a `for` loop improves your code and makes it "more elegant".  You generally use a `for` loop when you know up front of a specific set of values you'll be iterating over, and a `while` loop when all you know is under what conditions you will want the loop to stop.  One is not generally any better or more elegant than the other.  Given that `6` seems like an arbitrary number here, I might think a `while` more appropriate where some less arbitrary condition has you stop looping.

Comment: You should break out of the inner loop once `root**power>alpha` since once that is true, it will be true for all future iterations (and you should do so without computing the candidate value twice).

Comment: This code will give the wrong result for some pretty small values.  I believe that the first value for which it will miss a factor is `64` (`2^6`).

Comment: @progrmatico okay I wasn't aware if the python3 tag significance and the existence of a code review. I shall do that now. Thank you

Comment: @Steve I had used 6 as the question said power should vary from 0<power<6. Okay i shall look into the while loop possibilities here. Thank you for your help!